# View Gradle dependency tree in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, gradle, gradle-eclipse

Is it possible to visualize the dependency tree from inside of Eclipse (e.g. the output of `gradle dependencies`)? Expanding the Gradle Dependencies tree in Eclipse is a flat view and does not show dependencies for other projects (e.g. if I have a dependency `compile project(':project2')`, none of project2's dependencies are shown).

Based on [this](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/does-gradle-eclipse-sts-dependency-tree-view/9116) it looks like a tree view is not supported?

Basically I'm looking for the equivalent of this in the maven plugin:

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

At the time of writing, neither [Spring Eclipse Integration Gradle](https://github.com/spring-projects/eclipse-integration-gradle) nor [Buildship](https://github.com/eclipse/buildship) provide a *Dependency Hierarchy* view we know from m2e.

I don't know when this has been implemented but you can do a `gradle dependencies` either on command-line or via *Buildship Gradle Tasks* view within Eclipse. This prints a nice dependency tree of your project's dependencies to the console.

Comment: This is very unfortunate

Answer (score 3):

Use gradle 'project-report' plugin to generate report in HTML format.

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/project_report_plugin.html

Add plugin in your build.gradle file:

`apply plugin: 'project-report'`

And generate report using:

`> gradle htmlDependencyReport`

Answer (score 3):

For me, it was simply one command

in build.gradle add `plugin`

```
apply plugin: 'project-report'
```

and then go to cmd and run following command

```
./gradlew htmlDependencyReport
```

This give me a HTML report WOW Html report

---

> Or if you want the report in a `txt file`, to make search easy use following command

```
gradlew dependencyReport
```

[image]

That's all my lord.